# C++ Class destructor

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers, destructor

How do I delete `map<char, map<char, char>> board_game`, `map<int, char> X_index` and `list<Node*>`?

How would I write a proper destructor for the classes `Tree`, `Node` and `Boardgame`?

```
class Search_tree {
    Node* root = nullptr;
    char playerColor;
    list<Node*> leaveNodes;
    
    // Constructor, functions ...

    ~ Search_tree(); <--?
}

class Node {
    Board_game* currentBoard = nullptr;
    Node* parent = nullptr;
    list<Node*> childs;

    // Constructor, functions ...

    ~Node(); <--?
}

class Board_game {
  public:
    // Boardgame
    map<char, map<char, char>> board_game;
    map<int, char> X_index;
    map<int, char> Y_index;
    // Figures
    Position figures[8];

    // Constructor, functions ...

    ~Board_game(); <--?
}

struct Position {
    char x;
    char y;
};
```

Comment: the have their own destructors, so nothing needs to be done, you should change the List to use unique_ptr not a raw pinter.

Comment: You don't have t worry about the containers with plain data. It's pointers and references you need to take care of. Use a smart pointer class instead of `Node*` and the default destructors will do nicely.

Comment: BTW, unless you have a good reason, use `std::vector` as your default array container, not `std::list`.

Comment: you should read about the rule of 0.

Comment: It boils down to the question of the logical _ownership_ of `Node`s. Should deleting a parent also delete all its children? If so, delete them. If they can continue to exist, they should not be deleted. A `std::shared_ptr` will keep the object around as long as _anyone_ is interested. Only you know how the program should behave.

Comment: Might not need pointers here: `list<Node*> leaveNodes`. List has very forgiving invalidation rules and it's a rare tree that shares nodes.

Comment: the first two are simple. You do not need to do anything in your destructor for `std::map` members. For manually managed pointers it is what Friedrich says.

Comment: As long as you don't use **owning** raw pointers, there shouldn't be anything that needs to be done in the destructor.  That is to say, the default destructor will do the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide who owns what. Then you should turn those "owning" raw pointers into `std::unique_ptr` and then you won't need hand-written destructors. A possible ownership structure might be:

```cpp
class Search_tree {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> root;
    char playerColor;
    list<Node*> leaveNodes;
}

class Node {
    Board_game* currentBoard = nullptr;
    Node* parent = nullptr;
    list<std::unique_ptr<Node>> childs;
}
```

Since `Board_game` does not contain any raw pointers, it already doesn't need a hand-written destructor.